# Pagination with Query String instead of Path

Tags: wp-query, pagination, urls, query-variable

Is it possible to use ?page=2 instead of /page/2 for pagination?

When I try and navigate to a url containing ?page=2 the query string is removed from the url before the page loads and although I understand that Wordpress removes unwanted $_GET parameters by default I'm not sure how to prevent this.

I'm specifially trying to use this for a custom new WP_Query() loop.

Is there a way to allow the page parameter to be kept in place?